# How do I give a distinct name to my anchor tag so that I can delete the specific dynamic row onclick?

Tags: jquery

My current script will add multiple rows in a table along with a "remove" link and should delete the specific row that I click on. The problem that I am having is that it will delete only the first one. I believe the issue here is caused by there not being a unique name, however, I am not sure how to generate that unique name and reference it in the code for the `delete`. Here is my code:

```
//1. Add new row
$("#addNew").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
$trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove" id="rlink">Remove</a>');
$.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
  // Replaced Name
  var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
  var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
  $(this).attr('name', newN);
  //Replaced value
  var type = $(this).attr('type');
  if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
    $(this).attr('value', '');
  }
  // If you have another Type then replace with default value
  $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

});
$trLast.after($trNew);

// Re-assign Validation
var form = $("form")
.removeData("validator")
.removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

    //remove row
$('#rlink').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: You don't need a unique name, you can drop the id and add the click listener to the class "remove". `$('.remove').on('click', function () { $(this).closest('tr').remove(); });});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an ID for the remove button, specially because each element should have a unique ID and in your case all remove buttons have same ID. Remove the ID and replace `#rlink` to `.remove` in your handler and then use JQuery's `.closest(element)` to find the parent TR element:

```
//remove row
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Lastly move this function outside the click handler.

Comment: This won't work because you are binding the event handler to all the .remove elements that exist when it is run, and the additional elements aren't present yet.

Comment: You are correct @RobertMcKee, I have updated the code.

Comment: When I try this I get "body is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

When you are generating multiple rows, you are giving it the same ID

```
$trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove" id="rlink">Remove</a>');
                                                         ^
```

The method that adds the event to #rlink will target the first one, because id should be unique.

I would suggest adding the event at the row creation to the object directly rather than using a selector.

```
$trNew.find("a.remove").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```